# nameserver not falling back

Tags: nameserver, resolv.conf

I'm trying to use several nameserver, each one is able to resolve some hosts the other does not.

Here is my resolv.conf :

```
options timeout:1

# This one is used to resolve hostnames for servers internal to my company
nameserver 127.0.1.1

And this one is used to resolve hostnames for docker hosts I have on my machine
nameserver 172.17.42.1
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
search lmc.universcine.com
```

When using this order, I cannot resolve the docker hosts. When I put the docker
nameserver declaration first, I can. How can I resolve both groups of hostnames ?

Comment: That is not going to work, the typical resolver library will only then use an alternate nameserver when the the first one does **not respond at all**. A negative response is still valid response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how this works. If you get a negative reply from a DNS server, the system will *not* ask a second server but just assumes the name doesn't exist.

You will have to configure your local nameserver to resolve your local names and then recurse/forward for all non-local domains and only use this local nameserver in your `resolv.conf`.

Comment: Oh ok I get it. Would you know how to do that, by change ? I'm using dnsmasq, but I have no `dnsmasq.conf`, only a `dnsmasq.d` directory…

Comment: This is material for a new question.

Comment: Here you go : http://serverfault.com/questions/711018/forward-dns-request-to-another-dns-server